# Flutter web page looks blur when I run the app in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dart, flutter-web

Flutter Version = 1.12.13+hotfix.6

Dart Version = 2.7.0

Chrome Version = 78.0.3904.108

When I run the flutter web app in chrome it looks blur. I have followed the following code sequence and commands.

```
 $ flutter channel beta

 $ flutter upgrade

 $ flutter config --enable-web

$ flutter devices
```

2 connected devices:

Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108

Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

```
 $ flutter create myapp

 $ cd myapp

 $ flutter run -d chrome
```

[image]

Comment: I have also tried flutter run -d chrome --release but still facing the same issue.

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32274 . The issue come on the chrome browser only. There is a work around stated in there also. Might want to check on this. Until they fix it, it is a bug not something wrong with the code or anything.